# ASP.NET refresh the page

Tags: asp.net

Say I have a file called First.aspx. If I change code code on First.aspx and the user goes to it after already being there before, is it true that IIS will automatically release the cache in which case the user will see the updated page and not the previous copy?

Meaning, IIS will automatically take care of this, I do not need special code to make sure the page is refreshed.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the browser plays heavily in this.